# New to python 3.6 from 2.7 - is flask still relevant for async calls with gevent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-asyncio, gevent

I am going to 3.6 now....

1) I see for my worker servers ...in 2.7 I used gevent with great success for running one worker per core with N gevent threads per core...

2) For my web dev..for low level..close to CGI as possible I used bottle with nginx/uWSGI with the gevent loop

3) For api's I used Flask with nginx/uWSGI with the gevent loop

My api apps are screaming fast...and faster then nodejs for async calls to my backend databases...

Enter 3.6 ... I am confused....

1) It appears I can run my workers using asyncio since not dependent on a framework...so here I am OK

2) It appears that gevent is available for 3.6 and I assume I can still use gevent for flask with  the nginx/uWSGI with the gevent loop

3) uWSGI supports asyncio

4) flask support for asyncio does not seem to be widely supported

5) I refuse to use Django ...so dont event go there.. :)

So my question is that if I want to embrace asyncio with 3.6 is it bye-bye Flask in favor of e.g. aiohttp or sanic?

On other words...those that build async api's for python 2.7 how did you transition to 3.6 while maintaining non blocking calls?

It appears that I can still use gevent with flask with python 3 but this is a monkey patch to force async non blocking calls whereas asyncio is native and part of the STL...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Flask + gevent works like a charm for python 3.6. There is no any close solution to Flask-Admin and other robust time-tested libraries (like SQLAlchemy). For real applications I can get the same amount of rps from a flask as for aiohttp or sanic or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to go with asyncio preferably aiohttp which is more mainstream.